# How to apply localization without Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

[image: No file in the list]

I don't use storyboard or xib for this project (full code)
When I add new localization, it shows no file in the list, and when I press Finish, no folder created.

Comment: Have you created a localisable.strings file and used that through the project so far?

Comment: Is this what your are looking for?
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Comment: Yeah, I created it manually. Not used yet. I want to add an italian version.

Comment: @GajendraMali I tried to follow that tutorial, but It didn't work because I don't use storyboard and no file appear in the list, as my picture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a `Localizable.strings` file. If you already have that, select the file in the left panel. Then, click the button that should be in the right panel that says "Localize..."

[image]

Once you do this, you should be able to add other localizations the way you were trying to.

Comment: Thank you, really confused for a day. :D

Comment: I put english to italian in italian strings file.
What should I put in the english strings file? (The base language is english)

Comment: Put English strings in the English strings file. (e.g. `"Hello" = "Hello"`) In the Italian, you would put `"Hello" = "Ciao"`

Comment: And what if I don't have such file?

Comment: To create `Localizable.strings` file, follow this: https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881