# No resource files found for Localization in swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

I am working with xcode 7.3 . When I tried to localize my app , I saw in the tutorial that I need to check the "Use Base Internationalization" box in project -> info .. and select the the storyboard from the popup that appears. But when I try to do that , I get the popup but there are no resource files available. I am not able to understand why is this happening . Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently and according to other SO Qs/answers, if you don't use a storyboard, it could be one of the reasons you don't see any resources in the popup window for localization.

In this case, you need to use `Localizable.strings` file and `Localize` menu in the right info pane.

Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420865/how-to-apply-localization-without-storyboard) for more info.